# C++ ссылки на указатели

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

У меня есть метод, с вот такой сигнатурой: `void push(Object*& object);`

Я пытаюсь его вызвать вот так:

```
RelaxString* data = new RelaxString("Lol");

s.push(data);
s1.push(data);
```

`RelaxString` - это наследник класса `Object`

Но VisualStudio говорит следующее: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне решить эту проблему? Мне надо чтобы указатель принимался по ссылке, то есть чтобы я мог изменять адрес, на который он указывает.

Answer (score 4):

Ссылка на указатель на Object не может ссылаться на указатель на RelaxString. Так как типы указатель на Object и указатель на RelaxString никак не связаны. Соответственно необходимо сначала создать указатель на базовый класс:

```
RelaxString * p_data{new RelaxString("Lol")};
Object * p_object{static_cast<Object *>(p_data)};
s.push(p_object);
```

Вообще говоря, передача указателя по ссылке в С++ может намекать на то, что вы делаете что-то не так. Особенно когда метод называется `push`.

Comment: я делаю стек, для ЯП своего

Comment: @Lofectr Взяли бы `std::vector` и не мучались.

Comment: Согласен: " Вообще говоря, передача указателя по ссылке в С++ может намекать на то, что вы делаете что-то не так. Особенно когда метод называется push."